# Session die after email validation error Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I have form that user can change it is own email. But when validation error occured or some constrait failed session die and user is redirected to login page. Important to note that user is authenticated by user and password from database. Thanks for helping

UPDATE

I just added User.php file for more details.

```
namespace App\Form;

class ChangeEmailType extends AbstractType
{
    private $translator;
    private $transformer;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator, DateTimeToStringTransformer $transformer)
    {
        $this->transformer = $transformer;
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => $this->translator->trans('email'),
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
        ))
        ->add('updationDate', HiddenType::class, array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => false,
        ));

        $builder->get('updationDate')->addModelTransformer($this>transformer);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\Entity\User',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'change-email-form')
        ));
    }
}
```

UserController.php

```
/**
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 * @Route("/profile/change-email", name="change email")
 */
public function changeEmail(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $form = $this->createForm(ChangeEmailType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        try
        {
            $this->entityManager->lock($this->getUser(), LockMode::OPTIMISTIC, $user->getUpdationDate());
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', $this->translator->trans('email_is_successfully_changed'));
            return $this->redirectToRoute('dashboard');
        }
        catch (OptimisticLockException $exception)
        {
            $this->addFlash('success', $this->translator->trans('data_is_outdated_try_again'));
            return $this->redirectToRoute('change email');
        }
    }

    return $this->render('app/pages/profile/change-email.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

User.php

```
namespace App\Entity;

use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"})
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min = 6,
     *     minMessage = "Password should by at least 6 characters long",
     *     groups={"registration"}
     * )
     * @Assert\Type(
     *     type="alnum",
     *     message="Password should contains only numbers and letters",
     *     groups={"registration"}
     * )
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="field_is_required")
     * @Assert\Email(message="email_is_invalid")
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $theme;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $facebookId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $linkedinId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $passwordRecoveryHash;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $emailConfirmationHash;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @ORM\Version
     */
    private $updationDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $creationDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function prePersist(): void
    {
        $this->creationDate = new DateTime();
        $this->theme = 'light';
        $this->status = 0;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return ['ROLE_USER'];
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return 'salt';
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
         // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setPassword($password): void
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email): void
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getUpdationDate()
    {
        return $this->updationDate;
    }

    public function setUpdationDate($updationDate): void
    {
        $this->updationDate = $updationDate;
    }

    public function getCreationDate()
    {
        return $this->creationDate;
    }

    public function setCreationDate($creationDate): void
    {
        $this->creationDate = $creationDate;
    }

    public function getTheme()
    {
        return $this->theme;
    }

    public function setTheme($theme): void
    {
        $this->theme = $theme;
    }

    public function getPasswordRecoveryHash()
    {
        return $this->passwordRecoveryHash;
    }

    public function setPasswordRecoveryHash($passwordRecoveryHash): void
    {
        $this->passwordRecoveryHash = $passwordRecoveryHash;
    }

    public function getFacebookId()
    {
        return $this->facebookId;
    }

    public function setFacebookId($facebookId): void
    {
        $this->facebookId = $facebookId;
    }

    public function getLinkedinId()
    {
        return $this->linkedinId;
    }

    public function setLinkedinId($linkedinId): void
    {
        $this->linkedinId = $linkedinId;
    }

    public function getEmailConfirmationHash()
    {
        return $this->emailConfirmationHash;
    }

    public function setEmailConfirmationHash($emailConfirmationHash): void
    {
        $this->emailConfirmationHash = $emailConfirmationHash;
    }

    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus($status): void
    {
        $this->status = $status;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same error and I have fixed it, but show me the User class before

Comment: I just updated post and added User class

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem but I fixed it by to not passing object User to the formType.
This is my code

```
    $user = $this->getUser();

    // don't pass pass $user as parameter
    $form = $this->createForm(ChangeEmailType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $currentEmail = $user->getEmail();
        $newEmail = $form->get('email')->getData();
        $currentPassword = $form->get('currentPassword')->getData();

        // verify if the tow emails are different
        if ($currentEmail === $newEmail) {
            $form->get('email')->addError(new FormError('You must choose a different email.'));
        }

        // verify if the email is used by another user
        $userHasAlreadyThisEmail = $em->getRepository('App:User')->findOneBy(array('email' => $newEmail));
        if ($userHasAlreadyThisEmail && $userHasAlreadyThisEmail !== $user) {
            $form->get('email')->addError(new FormError('This email is already used.'));
        }

        // verify if the password is correct
        $verify = $this->verify($currentPassword, $user->getPassword());
        if ($verify === false) {
            $form->get('currentPassword')->addError(new FormError('Incorrect password.'));
        }
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $this->addFlash('success', 'The email has been successfully modified.');
            $user->setEmail($newEmail);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('profile_change_email');
        }
    }


    public function verify($input, $existingHash)
    {
        $hash = password_verify($input, $existingHash);

        return $hash === true;
     }
```